# Is it possible to a VM inside a VM (e.g., KVM on Vmware)?

Tags: vmware-fusion, virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization, eucalyptus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to setup a virtual machine inside another virtual machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine)

I'd like to do some development on [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/), an open source project which provides an Amazon EC2 interface for launching virtual machine instances on a collection of privately managed nodes.

I'd really like to be able to do some of the development on my desktop, rather than having to deploy Eucalyptus on our shared local cluster each time I make a change to the source code. (Especially since there are a group of us sharing that test cluster).

Unfortunately, my desktop machine is a Mac, which won't run Eucalyptus natively. I do have VMWare Fusion, and it would be really nice if I could do my Eucalyptus testing inside a VMWare instance. The problem is, to test out Eucalyptus, it will have to launch (KVM or Xen) VM instances.

I've got no idea if it's possible to actually launch a KVM or Xen instance inside a VMWare instance.

Comment: see: http://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine & http://serverfault.com/questions/127141/i-need-to-get-vmware-server-running-inside-of-a-vmware-esxi-virtual-machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo dawg.

Yes, you can, although it's a lot slower.

Comment: Significantly slower, and sometimes just doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Tom O'Connor: I've had zero problems with kvm/xen under VMWare and I've used kvm extensively under VMWare. Do you have any links re the "just doesn't work at all." bit?

Comment: I've never published my findings WRT this.  I could probably dig out some test cases if i had the time/inclination.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - but it's a bad idea.

Also this question has been asked A LOT on this site before, when you typed your question into the dialogue box a lot of previous questions were listed in the, usually vain, attempt to get people to look at these before duplication the question again - can I ask that you look at these next time please.