# Can you recursively run Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to setup a virtual machine inside another virtual machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine)

A VM inside of a VM?

Comment: Have a look at this SF question http://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: 'Cos you've watched Inception one too many times ;-)

Comment: @Gaius...so...you bluescreen each WinVM in succession to get back to the host?

Answer (score 3):

The ServerFault question is slightly out of date, and I only know the answer for the VMware platform. Short answer: yes, with restrictions. The latest versions of Workstation and ESX support running the latest version of ESX inside a VM for demonstration purposes. You can then build up a guest VM and run that from inside the guest ESX instance. You do need to edit the VM config though to turn on some advanced options.

Here's some info: http://www.vcritical.com/2009/05/vmware-esx-4-can-even-virtualize-itself/

Again, VMware does support this configuration, but only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: There's talk that it is also possible with VirtualBox too.

Answer (score 2):

Not seriously. YOu can with software simulation (slow). But hardware virtualization (fast) only supports ONE layer. Because noone seriously needs more.

Answer (score 2):

I have had success in running ESX under fusion 2.0, with several VMs but as other have mentioned it did require a bit of tweaking to get it running. I assume this is mostly for testing so I can see the reasons for doing it as was with my case. I cant imagine anyone doing this for production.

Also, as someone did point out it does require a bit of resources but I was able to manage all this on a mac pro with 4GB.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can but you would be highly limited to resources. I recommend VirtualBox for something like this... and a lot of RAM