# How to run a VMWare Server virtual machine in a ESXi virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-server, vmware-esxi

I installed VMWare Server 2 in a Centos 5.2 virtual machine which runs in a VMWare ESXi Server. When I try to start, via browser, a VM I created in VMWare Server, it gives me the following message: "You may not power on a virtual machine in a virtual machine.". Is there a way to put the VM to work?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are trying to run a VM inside of a VM?

Comment: That's by design. Is there something that you specifically need VMWare Server for when you already have an ESXi system?

Answer (score 8):

- Starting a land-war in Asia
- Inventing the hoola-hoop
- Trying to VM inside a VM

All **bad** ideas

Comment: +1 for the land-war in Asia. But you forgot: "Never go against a Sicilian when death is on the line". :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with starting a VM inside a VM, in fact, VMware now directly supports this feature.

Comment: Just because something works and is supported does not make it a good idea, have you tried it? did it work in a way you'd be happy to support in production? well I, and a number of other SF'er and others outside SF have - and we agree that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine).  It may not work with VMware Server, but if it works with ESX/ESXi, it probably will.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use VMware Converter (free standalone) to convert the VM to ESX format and save yourself some machine power by not doing VM-inside-VM?

Comment: Because my concern is not about weight on the server, but in the clients, which are old desktops with serious processment restrictions, unable to run the heavy-load VMWare ESXi client (vSphere), but perfectly able to run the VMWare Server 2 browser client. But instead of going on trying this experimental "nested virtualizaion", I'm thinking about simply substitute VMWare ESXi by VMWare Server.

Comment: In this case you may want to look at VMware View. Kinda like Terminal Services, but with VMs.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation now supports this feature, you can run ESXi via Workstation.

See http://communities.vmware.com/community/beta/ws