# vmware on Hyper-v

Tags: vmware-server, hyper-v

I'm wondering if it will be possible to install vmware server on a hyper-v image?

Currently I get an error when trying to install.

```
Setup cannot continue becuase microsofts hyper-v is being used. Please disable it, reboot and start the VMWare Server installation again.
```

Comment: Why? (this is almost universally a bad idea...)

Comment: "Image" is a bit unclear. I'm guessing youre asking:
I'm wondering if it will be possible to install vmware server on a windows computer that has the Hyper-V role installed?"

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to this question:

[How to run VMWare ESX or ESXi in a virtual machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it using this workaround. I've never tried it myself.

http://blog.baeke.info/blog/_archives/2007/12/18/3416738.html

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of VMware Workstation and Server check wether Hyper-V is enabled on the computer you're installing on. Simply remove the Hyper-V feature before installing VMware. The reason they do this is that only one hypervisor is allowed "at a time" (which is not a Microsoft or VMware problem, it's just the way the arcitecture is).