# Installing ESXi 4.1 inside vmware server 2.0.2

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server

I have tried several times running ESXi 4.1 inside vmware server 2.0 installed on Win7-64 bit. 
The problem is that the installation is stuck on welcome screen asking to press enter to continue (or Esc or R to repair). Nothing seems to let it proceed. I have followed all the suggestion illustrated. 
Any other idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the processor, have you got the VX bit enabled?

Comment: Yes, VT is enabled and the vmx config file has been modified as stated here (http://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine/163376#163376)
Processor il Core 2 duo P8700.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks MisterJaytee. Worked, at least in so much as resolving the keyboard issue - then came "F11" time - simply received (in summary format): 
"vmware esxi 4.1 installation:
Installation operation failed!

The installation operation has encountered a fatal error:

Unable to find system image to install. This is due to the image not being mounted correctly or the CD-ROM not being supported operation
.... record info ... before rebooting ...
supermicro, x7dcl, 0123456789, phoenix technologies ltd...
 reboot". 
Found sites that talked a lot about corrupt ESXi4.1 installer downloads - n

Comment: Thanks my VMware ESXi 4.1.0 installation works.  I'm using VMware Workstation 6.5.4 on Windows 7 Pro x64 host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a long time since you posted this issue, but I had the same issue myself.

It seems that a lot of people are having keyboard problems with ESXi 4.1, but the main resolution has been to plug in a different kind of keyboard - not very useful if you're trying to install ESXi on top of VMWare Server.

Anyway, taking a slightly different approach, I experimented with the kernel boot parameters and I found that adding `acpi=off` to the command line allowed the installation to continue.

So to do this, at the VMVisor (ESXi) boot menu, press `Tab`. Change the command line to read:

`mboot.c32 vmkboot.gz acpi=off --- vmkernel.gz --- sys.vgz --- cim.vgz --- ienviron.vgz --- install.vgz`

You should now be able to press `Enter` at the appropriate point and continue your installation.

After installation, you'll find the keyboard doesn't work again. This is okay as you can do everything from the VSphere Client anyway. But if you want the keyboard to work at the console, then first install the VSphere client.

Then connect to your ESXi machine and click the `Configuration` tab.
Under `Software` you should find an `Advanced Settings` option (scroll down if you can't see it).
Select this option then click `VMkernel`.
Now uncheck the box that says `VMkernel.Boot.ACPI`.
And click `OK`.

When you Reboot your ESXi machine (you can do this from the VSphere Client), you should now be able to use the keyboard at the console.

Comment: I'm glad someone else benefited from my hard work! If that's worked, could you tick the answer. Thanks.