# Recursive virtualization - Is it possible?

Tags: virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualization: Guest in guest?](https://serverfault.com/questions/274424/virtualization-guest-in-guest)

Is it possible to run a virtual machine under a virtual machine ?

Comment: I thought of this the other day. I wonder if you can measure the performance loss the deeper the VM's go. A VMware inside a Hyper-V inside a VMWare? Hmmm... inside virtualbox?

Comment: 2 words: VM Inception!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, but not with ahrdware acceleration - the processor only has one ring 0. For the hyper-visor.

The sense of it is academic, though - it makes NO sense from an admin perspective.

Comment: ...but Linux kernel 3.1 is going to add this functionality. With all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

esxi 4.1 can virtualize itself.

Comment: As can Linux's KVM.  http://avikivity.blogspot.com/2008/09/nested-svm-virtualization-for-kvm.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is known a nested virtualization.  Here is a paper on same http://www.xen.org/files/xensummit_intel09/xensummit-nested-virt.pdf relative to Xen from Intel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with [bare-metal hypervizors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification), and is very common for virtualization lab environments. Not generally recommended for production though.

http://www.vcritical.com/2009/05/vmware-esx-4-can-even-virtualize-itself/

Answer (score 0):

Sure. For some reason not long ago I was running QEMU as an ARM emulator inside Fedora inside VMWare Server on a Windows XP desktop.

It worked well enough.