# Just curiosity about virtualization

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run VMWare ESX or ESXi in a virtual machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine)

If I install an EsxI, and then I try to virtualize an EsxI on my EsxI host, is there a chance that might work?

Just wondering, that's all.

Comment: indeed, didn't see this post before. I can delete this question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

[How to run VMWare ESX or ESXi in a virtual machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine)